# Merge dictionaries in a list on common key-value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What is the pythonic way to properly merge dictionaries in a list
Given list of dictionaries:

```
[
    {
        "introduced_at": "28.12.2000",
        "item": "Pizza",
        "item_price": [
            {
                "date": "01.01.2011",
                "details": [
                    {"price": 1000, "changed_by": "Dieter"},
                    {"price": 900, "changed_by": "Nina"},
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "introduced_at": "28.12.2000",
        "item": "Pizza",
        "item_price": [
            {
                "date": "01.01.2012",
                "details": [
                    {"price": 1050, "changed_by": "Dieter"},
                    {"price": 900, "changed_by": "Nina"},
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
]
```

expected:

```
{
    "price_dev": [
        {
            "introduced_at": "28.12.2000",
            "item": "Pizza",
            "item_price": [
                {
                    "date": "01.01.2011",
                    "details": [
                        {"price": 1000, "changed_by": "Dieter"},
                        {"price": 900, "changed_by": "Nina"},
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "date": "01.01.2012",
                    "details": [
                        {"price": 1050, "changed_by": "Dieter"}
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

The key `item` and its value in combination with their `introduced_at` can be found twice in the list so they may be used as unique idenfitiers to merge the entries on. As for the details, since `date` are both different, they should be displayed seperately. Duplicates as seen in `changed_by` Nina should be disregarded.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this. can you check it is correct or not.

```
dl = [
    {
        "introduced_at": "28.12.2000",
        "item": "Pizza",
        "item_price": [
            {
                "date": "01.01.2011",
                "details": [
                    {"price": 1000, "changed_by": "Dieter"},
                    {"price": 900, "changed_by": "Nina"},
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "introduced_at": "28.12.2000",
        "item": "Pizza",
        "item_price": [
            {
                "date": "01.01.2012",
                "details": [
                    {"price": 1050, "changed_by": "Dieter"},
                    {"price": 900, "changed_by": "Nina"},
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
]
ans_dict = {}
pre_list = []
for data in dl:
    if not pre_list:
        pre_list.append(data)
    else:
        for items, index in zip(pre_list, range(len(pre_list))):
            if items['introduced_at'] == data['introduced_at'] and items['item'] == data['item']:
                for item_data in data['item_price']:
                    for old_items in items['item_price']:
                        if item_data['date'] != old_items['date']:
                            pairs = zip(item_data['details'], old_items['details'])
                            add_dic = [x for x, y in pairs if x != y]
                    items['item_price'].append({"date": item_data['date'], "details": add_dic})

ans_dict["price_dev"] = pre_list
print(ans_dict)
```

output:

```
{
  'price_dev': [
    {
      'introduced_at': '28.12.2000',
      'item': 'Pizza',
      'item_price': [
        {
          'date': '01.01.2011',
          'details': [
            {
              'price': 1000,
              'changed_by': 'Dieter'
            },
            {
              'price': 900,
              'changed_by': 'Nina'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          'date': '01.01.2012',
          'details': [
            {
              'price': 1050,
              'changed_by': 'Dieter'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```